# Changing <td> background color according to array received as AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to change my  background-color according to values on an array.
So cose seems to work but i keep receing ALL  with only one color, instead of having it doing the validation and selecting the color accordingly.

I have already tried with JQUERY to do this based on AJAX response. Console says it works, my site says otherwise. I really need help.

The code below is one of my AJAX functions. It should print 1 green and 4 brown/red ones. Still I keep getting either all red or all greens.

This is the array received `[1776220,17 ,242332 ,1119098, 500633]`

```js
function listThem() {
  let color = '';
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/vehiculos/testServicio.php",
    data: "data",
    success: function(response) {
      let dinamica = JSON.parse(response);
      //VARIABLE PARA DINÁMICA DE SERVICIO COMUNITARIO
      //Aquíiiiiiiiii we are trying to reset
      $.each(dinamica, function(i, elem) {
        if (dinamica[i] <= 86400) {
          console.log(elem);
          color = '#51d847';
        }
        if ((dinamica[i] > 86400) & (dinamica[i] < 172800)) {
          console.log(elem);
          color = '#F18D05';
        }
        if (dinamica[i] >= 172800) {
          console.log(elem);
          color = '#E54028';
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'php/vehiculos/listing.php',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    /** Lets convert the string-like response into an usable object */
    let trueList = JSON.parse(response);
    // Some console checking
    console.log(trueList);
    /**Template that will be send to the HTML */
    let template = '';
    trueList.forEach(vehiculo => {
      /** Some back-ticks magics */
      template += `<tr taskId=${vehiculo.posId} > <!-- PAY ATENTION HERE-->
         <td class=''>
             <a>${vehiculo.name}</a>
         </td>
         <td style='background-color:${color}';>
             ${vehiculo.ultimaUpdate}  
         </td>
         <td>${vehiculo.phone}</td>
         <td>${vehiculo.category}</td>
        </tr>`
      $('#registros').html(template);
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: `$('.some_td').css('background-color',color);`

Comment: `&` is a bitwise AND operation. To compare values use `&&`

Comment: Made those changes but still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append()` instead of `.html()`. You are overriding the content in your loop.

```
$('#registros').append(template);
```

Alsp, I have added `else-if` statements and `&&` operator.

```
function listThem() {
  let color = '';
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/vehiculos/testServicio.php",
    data: "data",
    success: function(response) {
      let dinamica = JSON.parse(response);
      //VARIABLE PARA DINÁMICA DE SERVICIO COMUNITARIO
      //Aquíiiiiiiiii we are trying to reset
      $.each(dinamica, function(i, elem) {
        if (dinamica[i] <= 86400) {
          console.log(elem);
          color = '#51d847';
        }
        else if ((dinamica[i] > 86400) && (dinamica[i] < 172800)) {
          console.log(elem);
          color = '#F18D05';
        }
        else if (dinamica[i] >= 172800) {
          console.log(elem);
          color = '#E54028';
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps.

Comment: I corrected the lacking &, bro. But the .append() instead of the .html() is not working at all. (It actually creates another bugs)